# Regex to differentiate between different URL

Tags: regex

Is it possible to differentiate the following urls with a Java regex :

http://www.apple.banana.com/kids/

http://www.apple.banana.com/kids/toys/

I want to write a regex that can match only the second url.

Please help !

Comment: Yes it's possible, but a `substring` / `contains` based approach might be a lot easier. What have you tried so far? Can you further specify the expected input/output?

Comment: Try to write the regex yourself, and if you get stuck, ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example to match any url having arbitrary number of texts after the `/kids/`

```
String []inputs = new String[]{"http://www.apple.banana.com/kids/", "http://www.apple.banana.com/kids/toys/"};
for(String s : inputs){
    if(s.matches("http://www.apple.banana.com/kids/.+")){
        System.out.println("matched: "+s);
    }
}
```

So, it will always match the urls like `http://www.apple.banana.com/kids/XXXX`